# Use dplyr to group-by dataset and summarize mean and SD (standard deviation)

Tags: python, r, group-by, dplyr, aggregate

I have some python code that uses `.groupby` and `.agg` to convert a dataframe into a summary table, and am having trouble converting into R. My desired output looks like this:

Figure 1. Format for desired output
[image]

Imagine that the starting dataframe `df` looks like this:

```
Y1  Y2  Y3   Sex    X1  X2   X3    X4     X5    X6
1   0   1    Male   52  2    7.25  11.40  0.50  2
0   0   0    Female 42  1    2.00  27.00  1.00  2
1   0   1    Male   46  4    0.08  16.20  0.17  3
0   0   0    Female 60  3    5.65  2.00   1.68  1
1   0   1    Male   81  1    1.37  9.20   0.80  0
0   0   0    Female 44  2    0.87  15.40  1.00  0
1   0   1    Male   61  4    0.87  19.40  0.25  2
0   0   0    Female 46  1    2.00  7.20   1.00  1
1   0   1    Male   56  1    7.25  1.40   0.45  2
0   0   0    Female 54  2    2.00  25.20  1.00  3
```

I want to be able to convert `df` to look like Figure 1 in R. So far I've figured out I can use the `dplyr` package to groupby and summarize a dataset:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Sex) %>%
  summarize(
  m = mean(X1, na.rm=TRUE),
  sd = sd(X1)
)
```

However this only gives me the summary for the variable X1 and I need it to be grouped-by Y1, Y2, Y3 and the rest of the X variables.

So how can I code this so it looks like Figure 1?

FWIW, this is more or less the code I used in python but I need it for R.

```
Y1_ = df.groupby(['Y1','Sex']).agg(['mean','std']).round(2)
Y2_ = df.groupby(['Y2','Sex']).agg(['mean','std']).round(2)
Y3_ = df.groupby(['Y3','Sex']).agg(['mean','std']).round(2)

frames = [Y1_, Y2_, Y3_]
table1 = pd.concat(frames, keys=['Y1','Y2','Y3'], ignore_index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is similar to that from @juhyeon but (1) I don't combine the Y values with `Use` and (2) I do some renaming to get output more like the example.

```
df %>% 
  gather(DepVar, Use, 1:3) %>% 
  mutate(Use = ifelse(Use == 0, "No", "Yes")) %>% 
  group_by(DepVar, Use, Sex) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("X")), list(mean = mean, sd = sd)) %>% 
  select(DepVar, Use, Sex,
         X1_mean, X1_sd, 
         X2_mean, X2_sd, 
         X3_mean, X3_sd, 
         X4_mean, X4_sd, 
         X5_mean, X5_sd, 
         X6_mean, X6_sd)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 15
# Groups:   DepVar, Use [5]
  DepVar Use   Sex    X1_mean X1_sd X2_mean X2_sd X3_mean X3_sd X4_mean X4_sd X5_mean X5_sd X6_mean X6_sd
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 Y1     No    Female    49.2  7.56     1.8 0.837    2.50  1.83    15.4 10.9    1.14  0.304     1.4  1.14
2 Y1     Yes   Male      59.2 13.4      2.4 1.52     3.36  3.58    11.5  6.92   0.434 0.246     1.8  1.10
3 Y2     No    Female    49.2  7.56     1.8 0.837    2.50  1.83    15.4 10.9    1.14  0.304     1.4  1.14
4 Y2     No    Male      59.2 13.4      2.4 1.52     3.36  3.58    11.5  6.92   0.434 0.246     1.8  1.10
5 Y3     No    Female    49.2  7.56     1.8 0.837    2.50  1.83    15.4 10.9    1.14  0.304     1.4  1.14
6 Y3     Yes   Male      59.2 13.4      2.4 1.52     3.36  3.58    11.5  6.92   0.434 0.246     1.8  1.10
```

Comment: In the `gather()`. First argument is the column name for the variable name - `DepVar`. Scond argument is the column name for the values - `Use`. Third argument is the columns to be "gathered" (made long from wide) - they can be specified by name or as here, column numbers (1:3).

Comment: Thank you! I like that you split DepVar and Use into two columns.

Answer (score 2):

This is your data.

```
db <- structure(list(Y1 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), Y2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Y3 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0), Sex = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Female"), X1 = c(52, 42, 46, 60, 81, 
44, 61, 46, 56, 54), X2 = c(2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2), X3 = c(7.25, 
2, 0.08, 5.65, 1.37, 0.87, 0.87, 2, 7.25, 2), X4 = c(11.4, 27, 
16.2, 2, 9.2, 15.4, 19.4, 7.2, 1.4, 25.2), X5 = c(0.5, 1, 0.17, 
1.68, 0.8, 1, 0.25, 1, 0.45, 1), X6 = c(2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 
1, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

This is the code. I thought the Y1, Y2, and Y3 should be changed from wide to long format. That's why I use gather function at first.

```
db_pro1 <- db %>%
  gather(y, value, starts_with("Y")) %>%
  mutate(y_value = paste0(y, "-" ,value)) %>%
  group_by(y_value, Sex) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("X")), funs(mean = mean(.), sd = sd(.)))

# A tibble: 6 x 14
# Groups:   y_value [5]
  y_value Sex   X1_mean X2_mean X3_mean X4_mean X5_mean X6_mean X1_sd X2_sd X3_sd
  <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Y1-0    Fema~    49.2     1.8    2.50    15.4   1.14      1.4  7.56 0.837  1.83
2 Y1-1    Male     59.2     2.4    3.36    11.5   0.434     1.8 13.4  1.52   3.58
3 Y2-0    Fema~    49.2     1.8    2.50    15.4   1.14      1.4  7.56 0.837  1.83
4 Y2-0    Male     59.2     2.4    3.36    11.5   0.434     1.8 13.4  1.52   3.58
5 Y3-0    Fema~    49.2     1.8    2.50    15.4   1.14      1.4  7.56 0.837  1.83
6 Y3-1    Male     59.2     2.4    3.36    11.5   0.434     1.8 13.4  1.52   3.58
# ... with 3 more variables: X4_sd <dbl>, X5_sd <dbl>, X6_sd <dbl>
```

Comment: I agree, the Y values should be gathered.

Comment: This was a nice solution too.